# Django wizardview: how to set up step data without validating the form

Tags: django, forms, django-formwizard

What I am trying to do I have a view which has a shortcut form which will ask a user to pre-fill  some fields before a user is redirected to wizard forms.

For example:

```
class PreFillView():

    def post(self,request):
        # get the data from the form and save into request.session
        # Then http redirect to the wizard view
```

Then from this view, I redirect it to a WizardView. In the wizard view,  I catch all the information passed in from the previous view in dispatch function:

```
class MyWizardView(NamedUrlSessionWizardView):
     def dispatch(self,request, *args, **kwargs):
        #parse data from request.session
        #set step data using these data
   # Note these data fields only partially covered the form in the wizardview, there is still a couple of fields needed to be filled in the wizard view.
```

This almost works fine but the only problem is that it validates the form and pop up field error for the fields which are not pre-populated. I tried, if I only redirect to the wizard view without setting the step data, it is fine. It won't validate the form, so no field errors will be displayed.

I am pretty new to Django and not sure if I am doing the right thing and if yes, how can I avoid form to be validated after I set the step data for the current step? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement the [`WizardView.get_form_initial(step)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/#django.contrib.formtools.wizard.views.WizardView.get_form_initial) method in you wizard view class.

This method gets `step` number as parameters and it should return dict for initial data for the form for that step.

Comment: that works perfect! Thanks a lot @Rohan. however, I still have a minor problem, I also have a clean_[locationentry] method in the form to assist with prompting possible locations when user type in post code, now it is not initialized anymore. should I also initialize it in the get_form_initial ?

Comment: @rzhomx, yes I believe you can call method to get data you want par particular step.